# Passing "this" context to javascript function on SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have following funcion of ODataModel object:

```js
serviceModel.read("/Users(1)", {
  success: function(userModel) {
    this.getView().setModel(userModel, "userAuthenticated");
  }
});
```

I get error when invoke to `this.getView()` function. `this` is nor recognized and have null value. I've opted for using this not very elegant solution:

```js
var viewCurrent = this.getView();
serviceModel.read("/Users(1)", {
  success: function(userModel) {
    viewCurrent.setModel(userModel, "userAuthenticated");
  }
});
```

Anyway, I would like how is the correct way for passing "this" context as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read) you'll see that `context` doesn't correlate with the functions context.

To set the context correctly, you have a couple of options. The first is using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which binds `this` to the current scopes `this` value.

```
serviceModel.read(
  "/Users(1)", {
    success: (userModel) => {
      this.getView().setModel(userModel, "userAuthenticated");
    },

...
```

If you're running in an environment which doesn't support arrow functions, you can always use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which allows you to specify the value of `this` inside of a function.

```
serviceModel.read(
  "/Users(1)", {
    success: function(userModel) {
      this.getView().setModel(userModel, "userAuthenticated");
    }.bind(this),

...
```